# Apriori Association in Oracle Data Miner. Data preparation

Tags: oracle, data-mining, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I have a problem with data preparation to use Apriori Algorithm in Data Miner. Everything is fine if I have product in one column lets say:

```
 |TransactionID|ProductName|
  1000         |Keyboard
  1000         |Mouse
  ....
```

So the association rule could be: If Keyboard then Mouse. 
With one column Apriori algorithm works fine.

The problem comes when I want to use more than 1 column to describe "product". In DataMiner Apriori Model Creator I can choose only one column for ItemID.

For example:

```
|VisitID|DayOfWeek|PartOfDay|...some_other_columns
1000    |Monday   |Morning
1000    |Thursday |Afternoon
...
```

So generated rule could be If (DayOfWeek = Monday) AND (PartOfDay=Morning) then (DayOfWeek=X) AND (PartOfDay=Y)

That is what I want to achieve. One thing I don't know is how to make a View that will change all that data to one column.

I thought of creating a new table with every possibly option (for DayOfWeek 7 combinations,for PartOfDay 4 combinations = 28 options; for only 2 columns), and OptionID of that new table would be my ProductName. Then the little problem would be to map these values backward.

Maybe someone have some other ideas how to let it work?

Oracle 12g. Data Miner 4.1.2.20.